# Is asking for books/materials/videos allowed?

Tags: discussion

Like asking for lectures/books on "Revelation", or for certain topics like "The Bible in the light of today's science".

Whether it's online lectures, books, audio/video materials on a certain topic, is it ok to ask for them here ?

Comment: fair game in Chat!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really.

In general, on Stack Exchange we want specific questions with right answers, if you do want to request a resource you should provide a significant amount of information on what you want to get out of the resource so that there is a clear set of requirements on which to base an answer.

This kind of question is not one we encourage. We would *prefer* that you choose topics that interest you and ask questions about those (again, be specific, there are a lot of views on a lot of issues in christianity, asking for all of the views on a certain topic is generally too broad).

But, asking questions is often a way to *find* resources. Do some googling before you ask to see if you can find the answer yourself, and then if you still feel the need to ask a question, ask in a way that you *ask what you want to learn* (Again, boil it down to specifics). Then you either get the answer, or a lot of times you get an answer *and* some resources to investigate further.